# Meteor Buildpack for Cloud Foundry

Tags: node.js, meteor, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to get the meteor buildpack for cloud foundry running and its almost there except right at the end I get a node command not found error. I've confirmed that during the build I can run node and npm version commands. I get no errors until the instance fails to start.

Node gets installed into a folder called .vendor. I'm new to linux but is it possible that this folder isn't accessible at some point for some reason because of the dot? Meteor gets installed into a folder called vendor so I will try installing node there too. Can anyone think of something else to try?? I also tried changing the node folder to 777 in case it was a permissions thing. Far as I can tell the PATH variable is setup correctly.

I got the app deployed by converting to a node app and using the node buildpack but i'd prefer to use the meteor buildpack.

Comment: I assume you found a meteor buildpack on GitHub.  You may want to open an GitHub issue on that repository, its maintainers would probably know best.

Comment: I got sorted in the end thanks. Not quite sure what fixed it!